# Как добавить элементы на начало и конец svg?

Tags: svg

Здравтсвуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста:
Например, есть svg в котором нарисована линия.

```
<svg><path d="M371,689L371,583L516,583L698,583L698,520L506,520L506,557L575,557L575,531L623,531L623,567L494,567L373,567L373,343L471,343L471"></path></svg>
```

Как можно добавить в идеале (div) или другой элемент(чтобы можно было добавить css на него) отдельно на начало линии и отдельно на конец?

Answer (score 1):

Можно маркерами вставлять элементы в начало, в конец и даже в узловые точки.

```css
svg{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}
path{
  fill:none;
  stroke:rgba(0,255,0,.3);
  stroke-width:4;
  marker-start:url(#marker1);
  marker-end:url(#marker2);
  marker-mid:url(#marker3);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <defs>
  
    <marker id="marker1"  markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" refX="3" refY="3" orient="auto">
      <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="rgba(255,0,0,.3)" />
    </marker>
    
    <marker id="marker2"  markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" refX="2" refY="2" orient="auto">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.3)" />
    </marker>
    
    <marker id="marker3"  markerWidth="2" markerHeight="2" refX="1" refY="1" orient="auto">
      <circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" fill="red" />
    </marker>
    
  </defs>
  <path d="m20,20 h40 v40 h-30 v30" />
</svg>
```